# mydesc_table function in R

Tags: r, function

I am reading someone's code from Github, which contains the function `mydesc_table`.

```
tab1 <- mydesc_table(table1, by = "gender", 
                     digits = 1, 
                     iqr = FALSE)
```

I could not find this `mydesc_table` function anywhere on google. I tried to replace it with other functions and it did not give me the same outcome.

The question is: How to find a function if it's not available on google? Is that because the function is incorrect or the version/device are different?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: It could be a private function defined elsewhere. Can you share the link of github code?

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the GitHub code since their work is not published yet. I think you are right. Perhaps they developed the code elsewhere and adopted it here. Thanks a lot!